# Area of the largest rectangle bounded by $y=x^2$ and the x-axis within the unit interval

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find the area of the largest rectangle (whose sides are parallel to the coordinate axes) contained in the region bounded by the graphs of $y = 0, y = x^2,$ and $x = 1$ using *Mathematica*. I am not sure where to begin other than that the area of a rectangle is $l w$. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) Have you plotted the graphs yet? (2) The easier version of this problem assumes the rectangle's sides are parallel to the coordinate axes. The harder version does not make this assumption. Which version do you want to solve?

Comment: In a situation where you're not sure how to begin, it's usually best to try doing it by hand instead of jumping straight into *Mathematica*.

Comment: whuber - The problem assumes the rectangle's sides are parallel to the coordinate axis.
Jens - writing it down by hand I believe I would just substitute y with x^2 and then find the derivative?

Comment: the graph looks like `Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, GridLines -> {{1}, {0}}]`

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to investigate this problem in *Mathematica*. The first thing I might do would be to build a `Manipulate` panel that lets me explore the problem space.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[t^2, {t, 0., 1.},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    Epilog -> {Red,
      Line[{{x, 0}, {x, x^2}}],
      Line[{{1, 0}, {1, x^2}}],
      Line[{{x, x^2}, {1, x^2}}]}],
  {{x, N[2/3]}, 0., 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Manipulate image]

The red rectangle has dimensions `x^2` by `1 - x`, so it is a good idea to plot the expression `(x^2) (1 - x)`, which represents the area.

```
Plot[(x^2) (1 - x), {x, 0., 1.}]
```

[image: Plot image]

This shows a maximum near 0.66, which suggests the answer might be something like `(2/3)^2 (1 - 2/3) = 4/27`.

To confirm this, use `Maximize`.

```
Maximize[{(x^2 ) (1 - x), x > 0 && x <= 1}, {x}]
```

> {4/27, {x -> 2/3}}

Comment: Simple and instructive. +1

Comment: In an analogous manner `Minimize[{(1 - x) x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, x]` searches for minimum area *x*'s. Do you have any idea why it doesn't return `x -> 1` too?

Comment: @BoLe. I imagine it's because there isn't a (local) minimum at $x=1$.

Comment: It is a minimum, and it's more local to `x = 2/3`. :)

Comment: @BoLe. The expression `(x^2) (1 - x)` has no minimum at  $x=1$. Don't confuse the algebraic expression with its interpretation as an area.

Comment: With the added constraint (which you and I put in `Maximize` and `Minimize`), there is a minimum at `x = 1`, why do you think there isn't; do you think derivative must be zero at every extreme?

Comment: Please stop bugging me about this. My answer has nothing to do with `Minimize`. If you think it is not working correctly, take it up with WRI. Also, the the docs on `Minimize` state "If f and cons[traints] are linear or polynomial, `Minimize` will always find a global minimum.". Note it says "a", not "all the".

Answer (score 0):

For starter try and see that any rectangle will have first corner at some `0 <= x <= 1`. That makes its area `P(x) = (1 - x) * x^2` which has two extreme values:

```
Solve[D[(1 - x) x^2, x] == 0, x]

(* {{x -> 0}, {x -> 2/3}} *)
```

Mminimum, ie. zero at `x = 0` (rectangle as a line; also at `x = 1`) and maximum at `x = 2/3` with area `1/3 * (2/3)^2`.